# Find an occurrence in a table column using panda

Tags: python, data-science, gspread, find-occurrences

I'm a complete beginner using Python and I'm trying to find a way to know how much Female and Male I have in my table.
I've imported my table and printed it but don't know how to find occurrences in my columns

```
tableur = gc.open("KIDS91").sheet1
print(tableur)


CITY    CSP BIRTHDAY    NAME    GENDER
LOND    48  01/04/2009  Peter   M
LOND    20  06/11/2008  Lucy    F
LOND    22  23/06/2009  Piper   F
```

Comment: U mean u want to count all female and all male?

Comment: why don't you import your data as pandas DataFrame? Use `pandas.read_excel` if you're reading an excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

See pandas [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) -

```
tableur.GENDER.value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will be good?

```
import pandas as pd


df =  pd.read_csv("KIDS91", sep ='\t')
df.GENDER.value_counts()
```

a bit simplifying:

First line -  import pandas

Second line -  loading yours data frame to memory

Last line - return counted values from column GENDER in data frame named df.